# Regular expression for hexadecimal and some other strings

Tags: python, regex, python-2.6

My aim is to read a string and where ever find an integer or hexadecimal number, replace that with "[0-9]"
My string is:

```
a = hello word 123 with the 0x54673ef75e1a
a1 = hello word 123 with the 0xf
a2 = hello word 123 with the 0xea21f
a3 = hello word 123 with the 0xfa
```

Have tried with following:

```
b = re.sub(r"(\d+[A-Fa-f]*\d+[A-Fa-f]*)|(\d+)","[0-9]",a)
```

Get the following output:

```
hello word [0-9] with the [0-9]x[0-9]a
hello word [0-9] with the [0-9]xf
hello word [0-9] with the [0-9]xea[0-9]
hello word [0-9] with the [0-9]xfa
```

But the output should be like that:

```
hello word [0-9] with the [0-9]
hello word [0-9] with the [0-9]
hello word [0-9] with the [0-9]
hello word [0-9] with the [0-9]
```

Comment: Try using `r'(0x[A-Fa-f\d]+|\d+)'` as the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern should be something like

```
b = re.sub(r"(0x[a-fA-F0-9]+|\d+)","[0-9]",a)
```

to distinguish between hex and decimal values.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
re.sub(r"(0x[\da-fA-F]+)|(\d+)","[0-9]",a)
```

See http://ideone.com/nMMNJm

Comment: @DioF The `\d` handles decimals.

Comment: Right... It's early this morning.